# Why are lie algebra of upper-triangular $nxn$ matrices not nilpotent Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Is there an easy proof (without Engel's theorem) of the fact that lie algebra of upper-triangular $n\times n$  matrices (of the field $\mathbb{R}$) are not nilpotent Lie algebra?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "upper-triangular"? Is that strictly upper-triangular, i.e. zeroes on the diagonal? Or can we have nonzero values on the diagonal?

Comment: strictly upper-triangular matrices are nilpotent. So I mean matrices which could have nonzero diagonal.

Comment: Do you specifically mean the Lie algebra consisting of all upper-triangular matrices, or do you mean any subalgebra of the upper-triangular matrices that happens to contain a matrix that is not strictly upper-triangular?

Comment: I mean Lie algebra consisting of all upper-triangular matrices.

Answer (score 6):

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}_n(K)$ of upper-triangular matrices cannot be nilpotent, because it has a non-nilpotent solvable Lie subalgebra of dimension $2$, e.g., generated by $E_{12}$ and $E_{11}-E_{22}$. Hence it cannot be nilpotent.

Comment: Very nice and elementary way to do it.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you. I wanted to use the center, but unfortunately only the traceless upper-triangualr matrices have trivial center.

Comment: Well, that is then another good subalgebra to consider.